# Multiple databases (Postgresql in RDS) but same spring repository and entity

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-data, spring-transactions, spring-repositories

I have a use case where I need to create exact same `postgresql` database in two different regions. Everything is same in these two databases i.e `same schema and same tables and same data`.

I have a use to achieve `distributed transaction`. So if a request land in region-a and write to region-a database to let's say Person table, then exact same record must be either written in `Person` table in both these database or if there is any error, write attempt should be rolled back.

I am trying to figure out if I can attach two different datasources with same `Person` Entity and CRUD repository in spring so the `respoistory.save()` method can write to Person table in both the databases.

So far, I have come across `AbstractRoutingDataSource` but that is for achieving multi tenancy in the databases. Other solutions are found are slightly different where use case is to write different records in different database (mostly sharding based on various data points).

Does spring provide any out of the box solution so I can achieve transactional write to same table in two different databases.

Answer (score 0):

> Does spring provide any out of the box solution so I can achieve transactional write to same table in two different databases.

Depends on your definition of "out of the box" - it doesn't itself implement distributed transactions, but does have support for using libraries that do. It is however relatively complicated to get everything working correctly, and requires additional components to be carefully configured in your runtime environment.

Spring Boot 2.x documentation on distributed transactions is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/htmlsingle/#io.jta

The Spring Boot 3.x documentation is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.jta but it's also worth noting that for 3.x, the Spring Boot team have changed direction and decided that integrated support should be provided by the relevant JTA provider (cf. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28589 ), and so there's projects like https://github.com/snowdrop/narayana-spring-boot